# Which combining css technique?

Tags: css

Which of the following would you say is the best way to go when combining files for CSS:

Say I have a master.css file that is used across all pages on my website (page1.aspx, page2.aspx)

**Page1.aspx** - A specific page that has some unique css that is only ever used on that page, so I create a page1.css and it also uses another css grids.css

**Page2.aspx** - Another specific page that is different from all other pages on the site and is different to page1.aspx, I'll name this page2.aspx and make a page2.css this doesn't use grids.css

So would you combine the scripts as:

### **Option1:**

> Combine scripts
>       ***csshandler.axd?d=master.css,page1.css,grids.css***
>       when visiting page1
>       Combine
>       scripts
>       ***csshandler.axd?d=master.css,page2.css***
>       when visiting page2

**Benefits**: Page specific, rendering quicker since only selectors for that page need to be matched up no unused selectors

**Drawback**: Multiple combinations of master.css + page specific hence master.css has to be downloaded for each page

### **Option2:**

Combine all scripts whether a page needs them or not

> **csshandler.axd?d=master.css,page1.css,page2.css,grids.css**
>   (master, page1 and page2)

that way it gets cached as one. The problem is that rendering maybe slower since it will have to try and match EVERY selector in the css with selectors on the page even the missing ones, so in the case of page2.aspx that doesn't use grids.css the selectors in grids.css will need to be parsed to see if they are in page2 which means rendering will be slow

**Benefits**: One file will ever be downloaded and cached doesn't matter what page you visit

**Drawback**: Unused selectors will need to be parsed by the browser slower rendering

### **Option3:**

Leave the master file on it's own and only combine other scripts (the benefit of this is because master is used across all pages there is a chance that this is cached so doesn't need to keep on downloading

> csshandler.axd?d=Master.css
>   csshandler.axd?d=page1.css,grids.css

**Benefits**: master.css file can be cached doesn't matter what page you visit. Not many unused selectors as page spefic is applied

**Drawback**: Initially minimum of 2 HTTP request will have to be made

What do you guys think?

Cheers

DotnetShadow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would say **Option 2 - Combine All Scripts**. As your website grows, the number of pages will increase, and tracking which CSS files go with which files will become unmanageable. You might think some CSS is only used on one page, but I bet in the future that won't be true.

Once the user has visited one page, they will have all CSS and the other pages will be vastly quicker. (Although you might want to optimize your homepage separately). Think web *application*, not web *page*.

Comment: Oh and you might want to look at http://www.dotlesscss.com/ to manage complex CSS.

Comment: Thanks for that great advice about thinking of the site as a web application vs website. Definitely will look into lessCss. The reason this whole question came up was because I was watching MIX 10 video by Jason Weber (http://live.visitmix.com/Speakers/Jason-Weber 35:40) who works on IE9 and he mentioned how so many people combine styles that aren't used on various pages and how it impacts on browser rendering since all selectors need to be matched up against elements on a page etc

Comment: True, but only profiling will tell you whether you have a problem there. As a rule of thumb, network requests are almost always slower than what the browser is doing.

Nice to see the IE team giving the rest of the world performance tips....

Answer (score 0):

Have you measured the page loading time with Firebug or something similar? I'm asking because I'm curious wether it will make a big difference at all.

Anyway, I just wanted to point you to a CSS Framework developed by yahoo. They've got a very clean structure, and maybe you want to design your own framework in a similar way. They use a reset CSS File to create the same preconditions for every browser, which I find a clever thing to do.

[YUI 2: Grids CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/)

Maybe it helps.

Comment: I will have to look into profiling and check out YUI stuff thanks